# qml style differs from the same sld style saved in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sld, qlr

I am trying to save style that I made in QGIS via layer properties in *.SLD format, but when opening my layer and import this saved *.SLD style - it differs from the initial one!

As you can see:

**my style in QGIS:**

[image: QGIS style]

**my layer with saved *.SLD style:**

[image: SLD style]

All labels are disappeared and all contour lines become very thick! (width 0.1 becomes 1.0)

Why is that styles are different?

Comment: Does it have to be SLD? You could save the style  as a QGIS style file .QML format which will work when bringing back.

Answer (score 3):

Qgis symbology is not fully representable by the sld format. Make sure you're running he latest patch release as there's been many sld related fixes recently. Otherwise saving the style as a QML file is guaranteed to maintain the full range of label/symbol settings.

Comment: Yes, QML file is guaranteed to save my style completely, but I need exactly SLD. I'll try the latest QGIS version as you recommended

Comment: I've tested in 2.18.12, unsuccesfully...

Comment: I've solved my problem in notepad++ :  QGIS automatically assign 1.0 to width value, so by replacing "stroke-width">1.0< to "stroke-width">0.1< I get   required width